# To fetch duplicate distinct values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query to find out duplicate where column B have only distinct values(that too it should be different). Please find my input record below.

```
COLA    COLB
121 INTERNAL
121 EXTERNAL
121 EXTERNAL
134 INTERNAL
134 EXTERNAL
156 INTERNAL
156 INTERNAL
323 EXTERNAL
323 EXTERNAL
454 INTERNAL
454 INTERNAL
454 EXTERNAL
100 INTERNAL
100 EXTERNAL
100 NOTINTERNAL
```

Here I am expecting only one output that is for Col A with value 134 and 100. For rest all conditions, you can see COL B have more than two different values

I write something like this, but it didn't work

```
select qssource from
(select  concat(COLA,'',COLB)qssource from TABLE)aa
group by qssource having count(*)=1
```

Could someone help on this?

[image: Sample output highlited]

Comment: Your requirements make no sense.  `454` also has more than one distinct value, so why is it not being included in your expected output?

Comment: Can you get a native English-speaker to help you rewrite your question?   The way it is currently worded doesn't make any sense.   I'd help, but I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: When I say distinct value, all the values in the column B for a group should be different

Comment: SOrry for the inconvenience.  Let me try to explain again. I need the COL A value as output only if within a group all the values in the column B should be different. If there is any repeating value in COLB for a group, I don't want that record to be considered in my output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want here:

```
SELECT COLA
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY COLA
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COLB) = COUNT(*);
```

This will return every `COLA` value all of whose `COLB` values are distinct.

Comment: Sorry Tim for the confusion. My requirement is that  "I need the COL A value as output only if within a group all the values in the column B should be different. If there is any repeating value in COLB for a group, I don't want that record to be considered in my output.Grouping is done based on COLA"

Comment: @GIN  I am pretty sure Tim's answer does just that...?  Have you tested it?

Comment: @iamdave , I did test this and it's giving me output for the case with record whose value in COLA is 454, which is not expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, it work. I was trying to solve this from Morning onwards :-)

Comment: I have just tested this query on your test data and if giving the desired output.  Either you have implemented it incorrectly or your data and requirements are different: https://i.imgur.com/gvYyo8c.png

Comment: @iamdave, I was talking about the query which TIM provided me initially.

Comment: Great.  That would work well as a new question, but not as a comment here.

Comment: Okay Tim, then I will post a new question

Comment: I posrted a differe question now, link is for reference "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965563/to-fetch-duplicate-values-with-condition"