# To fetch duplicate values with condition

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query to find out duplicate where column B values are different. My requirement is that "I need the COL A value as output only if within a group all the values in the column B should be different and out of the different values one of the value in COL B should be EXTERNAL"

Below is my input data

[image]

My expected output is shown below highlighted in blue

[image]

In the output you can see, even though the values in COL B is different for the group whose COLA value is 156, I am not expecting that in my output since it doesn't have external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT test.colA
FROM test INNER JOIN (
    SELECT colA, COUNT(DISTINCT colB) AS cntUnique, COUNT(colB) AS cntAll 
    FROM test
    GROUP BY colA
)t ON test.colA = t.colA
GROUP BY test.colA
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN colB = 'EXTERNAL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
    AND MAX(t.cntUnique) = MAX(t.cntAll)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ac4fb778759a37b71a51ff64ea4d37e)